# How can a Workspace be created in AWS Cloud9?

Tags: ubuntu, cloud9, aws-cloud9

How can a Workspace be created in AWS Cloud9?

At present AWS Cloud9 only appears to show a "Create Environment" option (which is always an EC2 instance running Amazon Linux). There is no AWS option for "Create Workspace".

I would like to create an AWS Cloud9 Workspace that is running Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/lightsail-instances.html)

Lightsail instances are the easiest way to run AWS Cloud9 workspaces that are not based on Amazon Linux. You can also add Cloud9 to running EC2 instances, but since you seem to be asking about creating a new workspace lightsail is better to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can now choose the Platform - Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS option when you create the workspace in Step 2.

However, if anyone has had any success running this image on Europe-1 region, I'd like to hear about it. I can create the workspace in Europe-1 but I cannot connect to it.